# BIM 360 API, PATCH users endpoint, services associated to an industry role are note applied

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to apply roles for several users using the `projects/:project_id/users/:user_id` endpoint.

Roles are correctly assigned to each user, however the services associated to that roles are not applied at all.

As I see in several other sources, it seems to be a known limitation and I would like to know if there is any workaround I can use.

I can see that from the web interface, when a rol is selected a call to a `/project_users/:project_id/update_member` is invoked where a list of roles and services are posted and works as intended. Is there perhaps any undocumented endpoint I can use?

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, unfortunately, it is a known limitation, which we hear repeatedly. We can easily understandable use case in setting a project users. Sadly, we do not have a workaround. Here is a ID for the wish:

ACSADMIN-530 (was HQ-3034): “API wish: adding users beyond Docs”

Sorry for not being helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @MikakoHarada Is there any tentative date for a solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have the exact date. The admin team has talked about providing enhancement in admin API, targeting later this year. That said, priorities changes. Till we actually see it, we cannot promise. Usually when new API comes, our team reviews. But it hasn't come to us yet. So it will not be in the next few months.